# Spring security auto configuration not working in spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have included spring security dependency in pom.xml but the endpoints are not getting secured by default .This is happening in spring boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE but when i switched back to 2.0.3.RELEASE, spring security is auto configured and all the endpoints are secured

I am not even getting the following line when using **2.1.2.RELEASE**

Using default security password: ce6c3d39-8f20-4a41-8e01-803166bb99b6

Dependency added in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Autoconfiguration of spring security is also working  in 2.1.1.RELEASE but not sure why it is not working in 2.1.2.RELEASE.Is it something expected from 2.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE is released 6 days ago. Could be a bug. Did you open a bug ticket?

Comment: created a bug for the same
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6460